# How to add another div to slideshow in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to put a selected image into the slide show. The slide show will then automatically slide the image that only been selected.

My code is below, but I am not sure how to add Javascript to connect the image and slide show. As for now, when I select the image, it appears next to the image and not on the slide thumbnails.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
</head>

<body style="padding:0px; margin:0px; background-color:#fff;font-       
family:helvetica, arial, verdana, sans-serif">

<!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->
<!-- Generator: Jssor Slider Maker -->
<!-- Source: http://www.jssor.com -->
<!-- This code works with jquery library. -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jssor.slider-21.1.6.mini.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: true,
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
            $Cols: 9,
            $SpacingX: 3,
            $SpacingY: 3,
            $Align: 260
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = 
        new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1",jssor_1_options);

        function ScaleSlider() {
            var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (refSize) {
                refSize = Math.min(refSize, 600);
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }
        ScaleSlider();
        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        /*responsive code end*/
       });
   </script>
  <script type="text/javascript"   
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">   
  </script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        var output = $('#output');
        //$('#selectlist img').each(function(i, el){
        //        $(this).addClass('img' + i);
        //    });
        $('#selectlist img').click(function(){
                  output.append($(this).clone());

            });
        });
  </script>
  <style>
    /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 02 css */
    /*
    .jssora02l                  (normal)
    .jssora02r                  (normal)
    .jssora02l:hover            (normal mouseover)
    .jssora02r:hover            (normal mouseover)
    .jssora02l.jssora02ldn      (mousedown)
    .jssora02r.jssora02rdn      (mousedown)
    .jssora02l.jssora02lds      (disabled)
    .jssora02r.jssora02rds      (disabled)
    */
    .jssora02l, .jssora02r {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        /* size of arrow element */
        width: 55px;
        height: 55px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: url('img/a02.png') no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .jssora02l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
    .jssora02r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
    .jssora02l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
    .jssora02r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
    .jssora02l.jssora02ldn { background-position: -3px -33px; }
    .jssora02r.jssora02rdn { background-position: -63px -33px; }
    .jssora02l.jssora02lds { background-position: -3px -33px; opacity:    
     .3; pointer-events: none; }
    .jssora02r.jssora02rds { background-position: -63px -33px; opacity: 
    .3; pointer-events: none; }
    /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 03 css *//*.jssort03 .p                  
     (normal).jssort03 .p:hover      
     (normal mouseover).jssort03 .pav          
     (active).jssort03 .pdn          
     (mousedown)*/.jssort03 .p {    position: absolute;    
     top: 0;     left: 0;    width: 62px;    height: 32px;}.jssort03 .t {    
     position: absolute;    top: 0;    left: 0;    
     width: 100%;    height: 100%;    border: none;}.jssort03 .w,  
     .jssort03 .pav:hover .w 
     {    position: absolute;    width: 60px;    height: 30px;    border: 
     white 1px dashed;    box-sizing: content-box;}
     .jssort03 .pdn .w, .jssort03 .pav .w 
     {    border-style:  solid;}.jssort03 .c {    
     position: absolute;    top: 0;    left: 0;    width:  62px;    
     height: 32px;    background-color: #000;    filter:  
     alpha(opacity=45);    opacity: .45;    transition: opacity .6s;    -
     moz- transition: opacity .6s;    -webkit-transition:   opacity .6s;        
    -o-transition: opacity .6s;}.jssort03 .p:hover .c, .jssort03 .pav .c 
    {    filter: alpha(opacity=0);    opacity: 0;}.jssort03 .p:hover .c {    
    transition: none;    -moz-transition: none;    -webkit-transition: 
    none;    -o-transition: none;}* html .jssort03 .w {    width /**/: 
    62px;    height /**/: 32px;}
    #output, #selectlist { position:  width: 202px; border: 0px solid 
    #000; margin: 10px; height: 400px; float: left }
  </style>
   <div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; 
   left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden; visibility:  
   hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; 
    left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: 
     absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; 
     width: 100%; height:  100%;"></div>
        <div       
   style="position:absolute;display:block;   
   background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center  
   center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 
    0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div data-p="112.50">
    <img id="34" data-u="image" src="http://placekitten.com/80/80" />
     <img id="34" data-u="thumb" src="http://placekitten.com/80/80" />
        </div>

        <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/011.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-011.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail Navigator -->
    <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort03" 
    style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;
    width:600px;height:60px;" data-autocenter="1">
   <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;   
    height:100%; background-color: #000; filter:alpha(opacity=30.0); 
    opacity:0.3;"></div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
            <div data-u="prototype" class="p">
                <div class="w">
                    <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="c"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
    <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora02l" 
     style="top:0px;left:8px;width:55px;height:55px;"         
     data-autocenter="2"></span>
    <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora02r" 
      style="top:0px;right:8px;width:55px;height:55px;" data-
      autocenter="2"></span>
</div>
<!-- #endregion Jssor Slider End -->

 selected image: <div id="sumcount"></div><br />
<div id="selectlist">
    <img id="34" src="http://placekitten.com/80/80" />
    <img id="21" src="http://placekitten.com/81/81" />
    <img id="11" src="http://placekitten.com/g/80/80" />
    <img id="5" src="http://placekitten.com/g/81/81" />
    <img id="9" src="http://placekitten.com/g/82/82" />
  </div>
  <div id="output">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```